# PowerShell remove-module

Tags: sql-server, powershell

on a local Server I've got a bunch of sub-folders containing PowerShell-scripts, one of those is "sqlserver" folder contains Microsoft sqlserver module. I've got a daily task-scheduler job connecting a sql-server, there is a zip-file having the same sub-folder structure (with a folder: sqlserver) as on the local server.
The idea is to overwrite the local folder structure with the new structure from the zip-file.
The problem is the module "sqlserver" which I  need to connect to sql server and get the zip file etc. Trying to overwrite it I get an error. I've tried to remove-module but it doesn't work as well.
The code:

```
try

{       

    [decimal]$lokaleVersion = 3.01 # 
    $deploymentVersion = 0
    [string]$filetype = 'PS'
    if($zipObject = Get-ZIPFile -lokaleAdminDBVersion $lokaleVersion -filetype $filetype -build 0)

    {

        $deploymentVersion = $zipObject.aktScriptVersion

        if($deploymentVersion -gt $lokaleVersion)

        {

            Remove-Module -name sqlserver -Force 
            Unzip-File -zipObject $zipObject -zipname $filetype -modulePath $modulePath #error Access denied
            $SubFolders = dir ($modulePath) | Where-Object {($_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.Name -ne "sqlserver")} | ForEach-Object -Process {$_.FullName} -ErrorAction Stop

            Import-Module -Name sqlserver -DisableNameChecking -Force
            ForEach ($Folder in $SubFolders)

            {

                try

                {

                    $a = (join-path -Path $modulePath -ChildPath ($folder.Split("\")[-1]) -Resolve) + "\" + "installer.ps1"

                    if(Test-Path ($a))

                    {

                        & $a

                    }

                }

                catch

                {

                    Write-LogFile -Message $($Error[0].exception.message) -severity Fehler -modul $module

                }

            }

        }

    }

}

catch

{

    if ($error[0].exception.message) {$message = $error[0].exception.message}

    Write-LogFile -Message $message -severity Fehler -modul $module

}
```

It's important to overwrite the sub-folders (I'm updating the scripts) and the sqlserver-module should be updated regularly.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: there is a whole bunch of Errors, coming all from \SQLServer, for example: Can not delete output file: Access denied: C:\PowerShell\Modules\SQLServer\Microsoft.sqlserver.wmenum.dll.
It looks like an error from 7.zip which I use in the Function: Unzip-File..

Comment: You can't delete a module if its in use i.e. if you have any process using it. If your script runs any commands in that module, then it's in use.

Comment: as I said: I know it, I'm using at that point sqlserver-Module, as you can see, I try to remove-module, than overwrite the files and import-module again, but id doesn't work.

Comment: As soon as you run any command in the SQL Server module (or `Import-Module`) it will be imported and can be in use therefore which will NOT allow you to remove it. You should do your checks and remove it before it's imported.